# Erro ao retornar lista com Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, fluent-nhibernate

Dentro do projeto Web.API, criei um método Get() o qual retorna uma lista de objetos - IList. Essa classe PessoaAcesso tem uma lista de Log (1:N).

Ao executar o método Get(), ocorre uma exceção:

```
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException</ExceptionType>
<ExceptionType>NHibernate.LazyInitializationException</ExceptionType>
<ExceptionMessage>Initializing[RemyWebModel.Entidades.PessoaAcesso#1]-failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: RemyWebModel.Entidades.PessoaAcesso.Logs, no session or session was closed</ExceptionMessage>
```

Método Get():

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Getall()
    {
        IList<PessoaAcesso> pessoasAcesso;

        using (var session = NHSessionFactoryManager.GetSessionFactory().OpenSession())
        {
            pessoasAcesso = session.QueryOver<PessoaAcesso>().List();
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, pessoasAcesso, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
    }
```

Classe PessoaAcesso:

```
public class PessoaAcesso : Pessoa
{
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Login de acesso")]
    [RegularExpression(@"[a-zA-Z]{5,15}", ErrorMessage = "Login deve possuir somente letras e conter entre 5 a 15 caractéres!")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O login deve ser preenchido!")]
    public virtual string Login { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Senha de acesso")]
    [MinLength(5)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A senha deve ser informada!")]
    public virtual string Senha { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Cofirme novamente a senha")]
    [MinLength(5)]
    [Compare("Senha", ErrorMessage = "As senhas não conferem!")]
    public virtual string ConfirmarSenha { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Acesso Administrador?")]
    public virtual bool Administrador { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Acesso liberado?")]
    public virtual bool AcessoLiberado { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Perfil")]
    public virtual PermissaoPerfil Perfil { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Log> Logs { get; set; }

    public PessoaAcesso()
    {
        Logs = new List<Log>();
    }
}
```

Classe Log:

```
public class Log
{
    public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }

    public virtual PessoaAcesso PessoaAcesso { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [Display(Name = "Data/Hora")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy - hh:mm:ss}")]
    public virtual DateTime DataHora { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Ação")]
    public virtual LogAcao Acao { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Descrição precisa ser preenchida!")]
    public virtual string Descricao { get; set; }
}
```

Mapeamento PessoaAcesso:

```
public class PessoaAcessoMap : SubclassMap<PessoaAcesso>
{
    public PessoaAcessoMap()
    {
        KeyColumn("Id_Pessoa");

        Map(x => x.Login)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Length(MapLength.TextoCurto);

        Map(x => x.Senha)
            .Not.Nullable()
            .Length(MapLength.Texto);

        Map(x => x.Administrador)
            .Not.Nullable();

        Map(x => x.AcessoLiberado)
            .Not.Nullable();

        References(x => x.Perfil)
            .Column("Id_PermissaoPerfil");

        HasMany(x => x.Logs)
            .KeyColumn("Id_PessoaAcesso")
            .Cascade.All();
    }
}
```

Pelo que entendi não não conseguiu carregar os filhos "Log" por conta da session estar fechada, só não entendi onde estou errando. Por ocorre esse erro?

Comment: Como está seu mapeamento da classe PessoaAcesso ?

Comment: @Rod coloquei o código do mapeamento.

Comment: é problema no lazyload, você pode habilitar para sempre carregar os logs da sua classe, .Not.LazyLoad()

Comment: Mas ai sempre ficar carregando o Log é complicado. São muitos registros.

Comment: Aqui não deixamos mapeado HasMany, por esse motivo, quando precisamos, usamos join alias e retornamos, além de dar mais performance

Comment: O erro ocorre porque você está tentando ler `Logs` em algum lugar do seu código, não necessariamente no `Controller`. Pode ser na *View*. O NHibernate não devolveu uma Stack Trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema estava no bloco de sessão:

```
using (var session = NHSessionFactoryManager.GetSessionFactory().OpenSession())
```

No caso, preciso deixar aberta a sessão para que o resultado possa ser entregue completamente, no caso dos registros filhos - Log.

Sendo assim, removi o uso do using deixando a variável de sessão aberta:

```
public IEnumerable<PessoaAcesso> GetAll()
{
        var session = NHSessionFactoryManager.GetSessionFactory().OpenSession();

        return session
            .CreateCriteria(typeof(PessoaAcesso))
            .List<PessoaAcesso>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro ocorre porque o json serializer está tentando acessar a propriedade de Logs fora da sessão.

- Você pode acessar manualmente a propriedade, dentro do bloco using para forçar o carregamento dela.

Ou

- Serialize sua entidade dentro do bloco using. Assim todo o grafo da entidade PessoaAcesso será acessado corretamente.

**Tamanho do Log**

Você ficou preocupado com o tamanho da lista de Log, certo?

- Ou você tira o log do mapeamento do Nhinernate, ou
- Crie uma classe dto para a qual você mapeia sua entidade. E sua api entrega este dto. No mapeamento para o dto você ignora a propriedade Log.
  Você pode fazer o mapeamento manualmente, ou se apoiar no Automapper:
  https://github.com/jbogard

É uma boa prática isolar suas entidades de domínio do mundo externo, devolvendo um dto que melhor se adapte ao requisito da api.

Comment: Entendi, porém o que não fica claro é: 

Se a minha classe PessoaAcesso já inicia a lista de log vazia no construtor, não era para o fluent/json serializar essa lista vazia ao invés de tentar recuperar os dados de log? Lembrando que é lazy-load.

Comment: O que você acessa na verdade é um objeto Proxy que representa a instância da PessoaAcesso, e é o Nhibernate que controla este Proxy. Portanto, ele (NHiber), simplesmente ignora a implementação original da sua classe e não insere nenhum valor na propriedade marcada como Lazy. E aí, quando você tenta acessar esta propriedade, que na verdade está no Proxy, o NHiber já não tem mais a sessão para fazer uma busca na base de dados.